Instant Indexing Problem With Wordpress and Node.js
I had a new wordpress site and the instant indexing file was working perfectly. THEN made several changes to the site and it stopped getting indexed.  I changed almost everything back to the way the site originally was ( added plugins back, deleted all old posts, etc.) and did a test post last night.  Nothing is indexing.
My question is do i need to generate a new json key?, if thats possible?.  PLEASE HELP!
WP: Removed plugins i added like classic editor, added back old plugins, cleared all caches, UPgraded WP NETWORK
